# unable to select top 10 records per group in sparksql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am new to spark sql. I have a data frame like this.

```
  ---+----------+----+----+----+------------------------+
 |tag id|timestamp|listner| orgid |org2id|RSSI
 +---+----------+----+----+----+------------------------+
 |  4|1496745912| 362|   4|   3|                    0.60|
 |  4|1496745924|1901|   4|   3|                    0.60|
 |  4|1496746030|1901|   4|   3|                    0.60|
 |  4|1496746110| 718|   4|   3|                    0.30|
 |  2|1496746128| 718|   4|   3|                    0.60|
 |  2|1496746188|1901|   4|   3|                    0.10|
```

I want to select for each listner top 10 timestamp values in spark sql.

I tried the following query.It throws errors.

```
  val avg = sqlContext.sql("select top 10 * from avg_table") // throws error.

  val avg = sqlContext.sql("select rssi,timestamp,tagid from avg_table order by desc limit 10")  // it prints only 10 records.
```

I want to select for each listner I need to take top 10 timestamp values. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
select rssi, timestamp, tagid
from avg_table
order by timestamp desc
limit 10;
```

EDIT:

Oh, I get it.  You want `row_number()`:

```
select rssi, timestamp, tagid
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by listner order by timestamp desc) as seqnum
      from avg_table
     ) a
where seqnum <= 10
order by a.timestamp desc;
```

Comment: No for every listner value I need to records...So it wont work

Comment: @TejuPriya . . . Just a way to not have to list all the columns in the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Here we can used dense_rank also

```
select *
from (select *,
             dense_rank() over (partition by listner order by timestamp) as rank
      from avg_table
     ) 
where rank <= 10;
```

Difference Between **dense_rank()** and **row_number()** is dense_rank() provide the same rank/number to matching column[**on partitioned is done**] values in multiple row where as row_number() provide the unique row number/rank to matching column values in multiple row

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use "limit" in your query. (limit 10 in your case)

```
EXAMPLE: sqlContext.sql("SELECT text FROM yourTable LIMIT 10")
```

Or you can select all from your table and save result to DataFrame or DataSet
(or to RDD, but then you need to call rdd.toDS() or to DF() method)
Then you can just call show(10) method.

Comment: For every listner I need top 10 records.So the above query doesnt work