# pyspark sql unable to recognize SQL query command

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Community,

I have written the following pyspark.sql query. However, pyspark doesn't appear to recognize the SQL query 'TOP 20 PERCENT'.

```
#%%
import findspark
findspark.init('/home/packt/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7')
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('ops').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv('/home/packt/Downloads/Spark_DataFrames/HumanResources_Employee.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('HumanResources_Employee')
myresults = spark.sql("""SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT
  NationalIDNumber
 ,JobTitle
 ,BirthDate
FROM HumanResources_Employee""")
myresults.show()
```

As you can see from the results, pyspark isn't able to recognize the number '20'

Can you let me know if I have to reformat the number '20'

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o19.sql.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input '20' expecting {<EOF>, '(', ',', '.', '[', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'FOR', 'INTERVAL', 'CASE', 'WHEN', 'THEN', 'ELSE', 'END', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'SEMI', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'ON', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'UNBOUNDED', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'FIRST', 'LAST', 'ROW', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'INTO', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FORMAT', 'LOGICAL', 'CODEGEN', 'CAST', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'DROP', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'TO', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'STRATIFY', 'ALTER', 'RENAME', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'STRUCT', 'COMMENT', 'SET', 'RESET', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MACRO', 'IF', EQ, '<=>', '<>', '!=', '<', LTE, '>', GTE, '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', 'DIV', '&', '|', '^', 'PERCENT', 'BUCKET', 'OUT', 'OF', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'OVERWRITE', 'TRANSFORM', 'REDUCE', 'USING', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'DELIMITED', 'FIELDS', 'TERMINATED', 'COLLECTION', 'ITEMS', 'KEYS', 'ESCAPED', 'LINES', 'SEPARATED', 'FUNCTION', 'EXTENDED', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'LAZY', 'FORMATTED', 'GLOBAL', TEMPORARY, 'OPTIONS', 'UNSET', 'TBLPROPERTIES', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'BUCKETS', 'SKEWED', 'STORED', 'DIRECTORIES', 'LOCATION', 'EXCHANGE', 'ARCHIVE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'FILEFORMAT', 'TOUCH', 'COMPACT', 'CONCATENATE', 'CHANGE', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT', 'CLUSTERED', 'SORTED', 'PURGE', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', DATABASE, DATABASES, 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'COMPUTE', 'LIST', 'STATISTICS', 'PARTITIONED', 'EXTERNAL', 'DEFINED', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'REPAIR', 'RECOVER', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'COMPACTIONS', 'PRINCIPALS', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'LOCKS', 'OPTION', 'ANTI', 'LOCAL', 'INPATH', 'CURRENT_DATE', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 11)

== SQL ==
SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT
-----------^^^
  NationalIDNumber
 ,JobTitle
 ,BirthDate
FROM HumanResources_Employee
```

As you can see from above the problem appear to be with the number 20.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Please format the error message so we have a hope of reading it.

Comment: The question has been reformatted. I hope this helps

Comment: Crosspost https://python-forum.io/Thread-pyspark-sql-unable-to-recognize-SQL-query-command?pid=53858#pid53858

Comment: I've changed the code to make it as easier to for someone to help. It now looks like this: df = spark.read.csvdf.registerTempTable("HumanResources_Employee")
df = spark.read.csv('/home/packt/Downloads/Spark_DataFrames/HumanResources_Employee.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('HumanResources_Employee')
myresults = spark.sql("""SELECT TOP 20 * FROM HumanResources_Employee""") 
myresults.show(), but I'm still getting a similar error message: == SQL ==
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM HumanResources_Employee
-----------^^^ The problem appears to be with the number '20'.

Comment: ok, I followed the suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923353/unable-to-select-top-10-records-in-sparksql, and changed the code to myresults = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM HumanResources_Employee LIMIT 20"). It worked fine. But if someone could show me how to tweak the code so that the results show 20 percent instead of 20 rows?